# (CakePHP 2.x) $this->assign() with twig

Tags: php, twig, cakephp-2.3

Hi how use this part of code with twig,

```
$this->assign('title', 'Home');
```

not

```
echo $this->assign('title', 'Home');
```

I tried,

```
{% set assign = ('title', 'Home') %}
{% set this.assign = ('title', 'Home') %}
{% set assign = {'title', 'Home'} %}
{{ assign('title', 'Home') }}
```

But still don't work

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using `$this` in the context of a template (it would refer to some generated class instance), but you can perform arbitrary operations without printing by using the [`do` statement](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/do.html).

> The do tag works exactly like the regular variable expression ({{ ... }}) just that it doesn't print anything:
>
> ```
> {% do 1 + 2 %}
> ```

---

To access the view itself when using TwigView, use the `_view` variable:

```
{% do _view.assign('title', 'Home') %}
```

Comment: `{% do this.assign('title', 'Home') %}`

Dont work :(

Comment: Are you sure 'this' exists? Maybe you should pass the object to twig to use: `$context = array('obj' => $this};` and then in Twig: `{% do obj.assign('title', 'Home') %}`. Can't say any more because question lacks details.

Comment: Yes because
`<?php $this->assign('title', 'Home'); ?>` it's work
But,
`{% do this.assign('title', 'Contact') %}` don't work

I dont understand, and sorry for my english ^^'

Comment: I have find this, http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html, so I tried this : `{{ attribute('this', 'assign', ['title', 'Contact']) }}` but dont work too :/

Comment: Twig doesn't know what `this` is. Unless you pass that object to twig, it can't do anything.

Comment: If you're using TwigView for CakePHP, take a look [at the readme](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView/tree/9b22ff50151e66fe0cc182548e9b917292a42f18#accessing-view-instance).

Comment: Oh yes! Tanks you man!!

`{% do _view.assign('title', 'Home') %}` it's work :)

Comment: @MrSaooty Please accept the answer if it solved the problem.